# Sum qualifying values while looping between two integers

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements, sum, factors

I'm trying to set up a basic PHP code where it scans through numbers and calculates the total from a certain set of conditions. Here, I'm saying I want to add all the numbers between 100 and 200 that are even and multiples of 5. To do this, i thought I could first put those numbers into an array, then add up the array.

Something like this:

```
<?php
  $total = 0;
  $naturalNumber = array();
  $naturalNumber[] = $i;
  while ($i % 2 == 0 && $i % 5 == 0) {
    for($i>=100; $i <=200; $i++) {
      $naturalNumber[] = $i;
      $total = array_sum($naturalNumber);
    } 
  }
  echo "<p>$total</p>";
?>
```

But error occurs: `cannot use [] for reading`, is there any semantic issues here as well?

Comment: what is a "natural number" , numbers even and multiple of 5?

Comment: Where do you get `$i` from? You push `$i` to the `$naturalNumber` array, but `$i` doesn't exist before it?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I can just declare $i at the beginning though, right?

Comment: use this statement "$total = array_sum($naturalNumber);" after the for loop, so that it will calculate the sum only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop is incorrect:

```
   for($i>=100; $i <=200; $i++) {
         ^^
```

The first argument for `for` should be an assignment of a value, you're not doing that, you're just testing if `$i` is larger than 100, which makes no sense. `$i` was never defined in the first place, so you're effectively trying to iterate `(null >= 100) -> 200` -> `false -> 200` -> `0 -> 200`.

You want

```
for($i = 100; $i <=200; $i++) {
       ^---note this
```

instead.

Plus the nesting of the `while` and `for` is also just... weird. Why the `while` in the first place? All you need is the `for` loop and and `if` inside that does the various `%` testing.

Answer (score 0):

As "@Marc B" Sir did this solution clearly, But i want to share my own opinion. 
You may did this work like this way as well,

```
<?php      
  $total = 0;
  $naturalNumber = array();
  //array_push($naturalNumber, $i);      
  for($i=100; $i <=200; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0 && $i % 5 == 0) {  
        array_push($naturalNumber, $i);
    } 
  }
  $total = array_sum($naturalNumber);
  echo "<p>$total</p>";
?>
```

Comment: again the while loop is pointless. you should just have `for(...) { if ($i % 2 etc.) { array_push(...); } }`

Comment: @MarcB, Sir I did this. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific scenario, we can bake your factorial requirements to produce a very concise solution.  Because your starting value is a qualifying value and all qualifying values which are divisible by both 5 and 2 will also be divisible by 10.

```
$start = 100;
$end = 200;
$step = 10;

echo array_sum(range($start, $end, $step));
```

---

Now, if you want something that is more dynamic regarding factorial requirements, you can use a `for()` loop and conditionally exclude number by checking if each iterated number is divisible by all required factors.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mMDuM))

```
$factors = [2, 5];
$total = 0;
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; ++$i) {
    foreach ($factors as $f) {
        if ($i % $f !== 0) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $total += $i;
}
echo $total;
```

Both snippets produce `1650`.